# "Request Should Have succeeded, but was "400 Bad Request" error on Robotframework-httpLibrary

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework

I am using `Robotframework-httplibrary` for automating my webservice API, which has Header and Request body. Manually If I test these APIs using REST Client, the APIs works fine. However, from my Robot framework Testcase it fails.

I understand that the error is with testcase syntax or with the interpretor..`python2.7`(may be it is not supported)

Below is the test script:

```
*** Settings***  
Library      HttpLibrary.HTTP  
*** Test Cases ***  

Test Create Process       Set Request Header    clientID: vg_site1
                      Set Request Body      {"               "}
                      POST               http://localhost:portno/application
                      Response Status Code Should Equal   200 OK
```

`output:Request should have succeeded, but was "400 Bad Request"`

Answer (score 0):

Your request body probably isn't what you think it is. Because you are using spaces as separators, `{"            "}` is being treated as two separate words, and all of the whitespace is being removed. You will need to put a `\` before each space.

Comment: I am not sure backslash+space works... but one can use ${SPACE} that is longer but maybe more explicit.

Comment: My Actual Request body content is ->  {"stream_name" : "test_qaa_site1_mongo",
"source_topic" :"mongo_qaa_site1",
"source_provider" : "activemq",
"sink_host" : "172.16.1.243",
"sink_port" : 27017,
"sink_databasename":"igc_datastore_qaa",
"sink_collectionname" : "qaa_collection1"}     and I can notice that my testcase is failing  because of this json body..

Comment: @shilpakuppelur: I suggest putting the json into a variable, so that you can show it in the log before calling the keyword. Perhaps you have extra spaces in your json body that you aren't noticing.

Comment: @Brayan, Thank you for editing for my question and I found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my testcase there are two changes required

1. I need to Create HTTP Context with host name.
2. In Set Request Body we should not give any space or colon or double quotes instead use

   1. for assignment use =
   2. for space  use %20
   3. for to differentiate use &